# Connection between hair and maturity

Tags: kohen-priest, hair, children, nozir

Rav Yonasan Aibshitz (in Ahavas Yehonasan on the Haftorah of Emor), writes that growing hair is connected to preventing lust, (like we find by a Nazir), and cutting one’s hair is connected to wisdom (like we find by the Kohanim).

My question is: are there any commentaries who explain the reason for cutting a boy’s hair specifically at three years old, and not earlier, along the lines of Rav Yonasan’s explanation regarding a Nazir and Kohanim - that it is either connected to the boy’s wisdom or separation from lust?

Comment: I doubt it. 3 year olds don't really have either.